# wrapping through two arrays in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm developing a game project in C - recreation of board game Oware, and I need two arrays to wrap through each other.

I have a struct for the game and a few global variables, and an array per player, defined with the global variables within the struct, which makes each player have six pits to play in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define num_players 2
#define num_pits_player 6
#define num_seeds 4

struct gameState{
    int pits[num_players][num_pits_player]; //pits for the seeds
    int deposit[num_players]; //deposit for the pits
    int playerTurn; //keeping track of whose turn it is
};

void displayGame(struct gameState *game){
    printf("\n");
    printf("|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------|\n"
           "|score_p1|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|score_p0|\n"
           "|  %2d    |-----------------|   %2d   |\n"
           "|        |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|        |\n"
           "|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|\n",
           game->pits[1][0], game->pits[1][1], game->pits[1][2], game->pits[1][3], game->pits[1][4], game->pits[1][5],
           game->deposit[1], game->deposit[0],
           game->pits[0][0], game->pits[0][1], game->pits[0][2], game->pits[0][3], game->pits[0][4], game->pits[0][5]);
}

void makeMove(struct gameState *game){
    int player = game->playerTurn;
    int pitToSow;

    printf("Player %d's turn.\nPick a pit to sow(1-6): ", player);
    scanf("%d", &pitToSow);
    pitToSow--; // adjusting for zero-based indexing

    // Get the seeds from the selected pit
    int seedsToSow = game->pits[player][pitToSow];

    // Clear the selected pit
    game->pits[player][pitToSow] = 0;

    // Distribute seeds in a counterclockwise direction
    int currentPit = (pitToSow + 1) % num_pits_player;

    while (seedsToSow > 0) {
        // Distribute one seed to the current pit
        game->pits[player][currentPit]++;
        seedsToSow--;

        // Move to the next pit
        currentPit = (currentPit + 1);

    }
}
```

The error I'm facing is whenever the code runs, I get

```
|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------| /*initial print*/
|score_p1| 4| 4| 4| 4| 4| 4|score_p0| 
|   0    |-----------------|    0   |
|        | 4| 4| 4| 4| 4| 4|        |
|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|

Player 0's turn.
Pick a pit to sow(1-6):4
|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------| /*player 0's play*/
|score_p1| 5| 5| 4| 4| 4| 4|score_p0| /*works as expected*/
|   0    |-----------------|    0   |
|        | 4| 4| 4| 0| 5| 5|        |
|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|
Player 1's turn.
Pick a pit to sow(1-6):5

|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------| /*player 1's play, the error seems to be*/
|score_p1| 5| 5| 4| 4| 0| 5|score_p0| /*that it doesnt wrap through */
|   1    |-----------------|    1   | /*to player 0's pits when finished with its own*/
|        | 4| 4| 4| 0| 5| 5|        | 
|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|
```

Instead of an Ideal

```
|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------| /*initial print*/
|score_p1| 4| 4| 4| 4| 4| 4|score_p0| 
|   0    |-----------------|    0   |
|        | 4| 4| 4| 4| 4| 4|        |
|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|

Player 0's turn.
Pick a pit to sow(1-6):4
|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------| /*player 0's play*/
|score_p1| 5| 5| 4| 4| 4| 4|score_p0| /*works as expected*/
|   0    |-----------------|    0   |
|        | 4| 4| 4| 0| 5| 5|        |
|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|
Player 1's turn.
Pick a pit to sow(1-6):5

|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------| /*optimal player 1 play,wrapping to player 0's pits when finished with its own*/
|score_p1| 5| 5| 4| 4| 0| 5|score_p0| 
|   1    |-----------------|    1   | 
|        | 5| 5| 5| 0| 5| 5|        | 
|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].  The above is also missing a '}'.

Comment: It's confusing when you talk about array A and B but your code doesn't have arrays named that way.  I suggest you revise the question.

Comment: You should validate that pitToSow is indeed between 1 and 6.  Otherwise it leads to trivial out of bounds access.

Comment: `opponentPlayerIndex` is never used for anything.

Comment: You are better off specifying each test with a known starting state (like I had in an earlier revision) instead of running two rounds. That way each test is independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Always validate the return value from `scanf()` and in this case that the value is within the expected range.  I wonder if the `6` is `num_pits_player`?  If so use that variable to generate the prompt.
2. `currentPit = (currentPit + 1);` should be modulo size of the array otherwise you will have undefined behavior.
3. `opponentPlayerIndex` is not used for anything so removed it.
4. (Not fixed) Score is not updated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define num_players 2
#define num_pits_player 6
#define num_seeds 4

struct gameState{
    int pits[num_players][num_pits_player]; //pits for the seeds
    int deposit[num_players]; //deposit for the pits
    int playerTurn; //keeping track of whose turn it is
};

void makeMove(struct gameState *game){
    int player = game->playerTurn;
    printf("Player %d's turn.\nPick a pit to sow(1-6): ", player);
    int pitToSow;
    if(scanf("%d", &pitToSow) != 1 || pitToSow < 1 || pitToSow > 6) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pitToSow--; // adjusting for zero-based indexing

    // Get the seeds from the selected pit
    int seedsToSow = game->pits[player][pitToSow];
 
    // Clear the selected pit
    game->pits[player][pitToSow] = 0;

    for(int currentPit = pitToSow + 1; seedsToSow > 0; currentPit++, seedsToSow--)
        // Distribute one seed to the current pit
        game->pits[(player + currentPit / num_pits_player) % num_players][currentPit % num_pits_player]++;
}

void displayGame(struct gameState *game){
    printf("\n");
    printf("|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------|\n"
           "|score_p1|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|score_p0|\n"
           "|  %2d    |-----------------|   %2d   |\n"
           "|        |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|        |\n"
           "|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|\n",
           game->pits[1][0], game->pits[1][1], game->pits[1][2], game->pits[1][3], game->pits[1][4], game->pits[1][5],
           game->deposit[1], game->deposit[0],
           game->pits[0][0], game->pits[0][1], game->pits[0][2], game->pits[0][3], game->pits[0][4], game->pits[0][5]);
}

int main(void) {
    struct gameState s = {
        .pits = {
            {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
            {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}
        }
    };
    for(int p = 0; p < 2; p++) {
        s.playerTurn = p;
        makeMove(&s);
        printGameState(&s);
    }
}
```

and example output:

```
Player 0's turn.
Pick a pit to sow(1-6): 4

|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------|
|score_p1| 5| 5| 4| 4| 4| 4|score_p0|
|   0    |-----------------|    0   |
|        | 4| 4| 4| 0| 5| 5|        |
|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|
Player 1's turn.
Pick a pit to sow(1-6): 5

|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------|
|score_p1| 5| 5| 4| 4| 0| 5|score_p0|
|   0    |-----------------|    0   |
|        | 5| 5| 5| 0| 5| 5|        |
|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however, the example run I'm looking for is something like this: 
```Player 0's turn.  
Pick a pit to sow(1-6): 4  
player: 0: 4, 4, 4, 0, 5, 5  
player: 1: 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4```
Also, since I'm mimicking a board game, let's say player 1 pick their 6th pit to be sown, the results should look something like:
```player: 0: 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5   
player: 1: 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 0```

Comment: You want to edit the question with those two test cases.  It's easier to read and that way others don't have to read through all comments to figure out what the requirements are.  I believe revised answer addresses the two test cases you provided.

Comment: If that answered your question please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and patience, all I did was add a ```game->pits[player][pitToSow] = 0;``` statement after before the ```for``` statement for it to display as intended.

Comment: Fixed.  I lost those two lines in a revision.  My pleasure.